# Корректное наследование агрегируемых классов

Tags: ооп, наследование, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, actionscript

При сильном увеличении числа полей и методов класса возникает желание разделить его на смысловые части и аггрегировать их в главный класс как поля-объекты. Но проблема в том, что у потомков главного класса встаёт вопрос расширения функциональности, а для этого хочется наследовать от аггрегированных классов расширенные новые и заменить старые ими. А этого как раз сделать нельзя! Пример (язык ActionScript 3, все классы раскиданы по одноимённым файлам):

```
public class ContainerA
{
    public var subClass: SubClassA;

    public function ContainerA()
    {
        initSubclasses();
    }

    protected function initSubclasses(): void
    {
        subClass = new SubClassA();
    }
}

public class ContainerB extends ContainerA
{
    // ошибка компилирования! перегружать можно только методы
    override public var subClass: SubClassB;

    public function ContainerB()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function initSubclasses(): void
    {
        subClass = new SubClassB();
    }
}

public class SubClassA
{
    public function PrintA(): void
    {
        trace("I'm a subclass A");
    }
}

public class SubClassB extends SubClassA
{
    override public function PrintA(): void
    {
        trace("I'm a subclass B, inherited from A");
    }

    public function PrintB(): void
    {
        trace("I'm a subclass B");
    }
}
```

код в Main.as:

```
var containerA: ContainerA = new ContainerA();
var containerB: ContainerB = new ContainerB();
containerA.subClass.PrintA(); // " I'm a subclass A "
containerB.subClass.PrintA(); // " I'm a subclass B, inherited from A "
containerB.subClass.PrintB(); // напечаталось бы " I'm a subclass B "
```

---

Даже если вместо перегрузки поля делать перегрузку get-метода и обращаться к аггрегируемому классу через него, также возникнет ошибка компиляции, но уже другая: нельзя изменять сигнатуру перегружаемого метода:

в ContainerA:

```
public function getSubClass(): SubClassA
{
    return subClass;
}
```

в ContainerB:

```
override public function getSubClass(): SubClassB
{
    return (subClass as SubClassB);
}
```

Поэтому вопрос: как решаются (если решаются) такие проблемы в ActionScript и как решаются в других статически типизированных языках (Java, C#). Может быть есть какие-то костыльные, но удобные паттерны проектирования?

Comment: Это называется "ковариация (то есть сужение) возвращаемого типа". Ни в C#, ни в ActionScript этого нет, а в Java (JDK 1.5+) это реализовано - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Comment: Стало интересно - приведите результирующий код. И Вика щас увы лежит (

Answer (score 4):

- То, что вы пытаетесь сделать - некорректно, поскольку вы в `derived` классе пытаетесь изменить сигнатуру уже определенного в `base` классе метода, а ваш `SubClassB` **не унаследован** от `SubClassA`.

> Не теряя общности, можно говорить и про `public` поля, которые теоретически можно было бы равносильно подменить на пару `get/set`.

- Представьте себе следующий кейс:

  ```
  var b: ContainerB = new ContainerB();
  var a: ContainerA = b as ContainerA;

  // Какой compile-time тип, по-вашему, должен быть у этих методов?
  var x: ??? = a.subClass;
  var y: ??? = a.getSubClass();
  ```
- Если бы ваш `SubclassB` **был унаследован** от `SubClassA`, то в вашем методе       `'getSubClass() : SubClassA'` вы могли бы сделать `'return new SubClassB();'`, и это было бы правильным решением задачи.

> В момент, когда вы из метода, который должен возвращать `SubClassA`, возвращаете `SubClassB`, применяется `type contravariance.`

Comment: > public class SubClassB
>
> {
>
>    override public function PrintA(): void
>
>    {
>
>        trace("I'm a subclass B, inherited from A");
>
>    }

Выглядит, будто @d9k подразумевает, что `SubClassB` унаследован от `SubClassA`, но он забыл написать `extends...` .

Comment: да, я копировал код и забыл, спасибо